# Exchanging limit and evaluation of argmax

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

Let $g_n:\mathcal X \to \mathbb R$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and $f:\mathcal X \to \mathbb R$. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathcal X$, then does the following hold?
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(\arg \max_{x \in \mathcal X} g_n(x)) = f(\arg \max_{x \in \mathcal X} \lim_{n \to \infty}g_n(x))$$

If not, what additional assumptions would be necessary?

Comment: What is arg max and why do you have different smbols for X?

Comment: The different X was a typo (fixed). Is there ambiguity about what [arg max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max) is? Are you pointing out that my spacing is bad since the $x \in \mathcal X$ isn't centered?

Comment: X's are fine now, sorry I just didn't know what arg max meant

Comment: Isn't, in the RHS, $\arg\max_x \lim_n g_n(x)$ exactly $\arg\max_x f(x)$?

Comment: Also, why is f(arg max g_n) well defined?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, and so the right side is $\max_x f(x)$.

Comment: @zhw The domain of $g_n$ is $\mathcal X$, so $\arg \max g_n(x) \subseteq \mathcal X$, and so $f$ is defined on all elements of $\arg \max g_n(x)$. You're right that I'm abusing notation though - when I write $\arg \max g_n(x)$ I really mean any element of $\arg \max g_n(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb R.$ For $n\in \mathbb N,$ define $g_n(1-1/n) = 2, g_n(1) = 1,$ $g_n = 0 $ everywhere else. Define $f(1) = 1,$ $f = 0 $ everywhere else. Then $g_n \to f$ pointwise everywhere. But $\arg \max g_n = \{1-1/n\},$ so $f(\arg \max g_n ) = 0$ for all $n.$ Obviously $f(\arg \max f) = f(1) = 1.$ So the desired limit relation fails. (There is still a problem with all this: $\arg \max g_n$ is a set, and so is $\arg \max f.$ We have a certain sequence $A_n$ in the domain and the question has the form: Does $f(A_n) \to f(A)?$ What does that even mean?)

Comment: Thanks for the counter example!